# Converting CSS linear-gradient to react-native-linear-gradient

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

Given this gradient from Figma:
`background: linear-gradient(329.69deg, #60FFE2 -13.87%, #00B0FF 117.6%);`

How can I use it in React Native with `react-native-linear-gradient`?

My problem is that in `react-native-linear-gradient` the locations must be between 0 and 1, and in my opinion I would have to set -0.1387 and 1.176, which results in a black background. And of course just setting 0 and 1 does not look as designed.